# Cannot restrain text properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm not sure how to make restraints so that my text isn't hidden by the app bar at the top.
[image]

I've tried making the restraints have different anchor points, but I'm not sure how to make it not get hidden.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textintro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Droid Desserts"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp" />
```

Comment: add tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is not constrained to anywhere, so it will jump to (0,0) as the error is saying:

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to 
>    (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

**Notice that the `tools` attributes  (see below) will only affect your preview but not the run time:**

- Start by removing those attributes:

  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp"`
  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp"`

  Those attributes are what made you see your view behind your toolbar
- And now you once you can see your views as they will be on run time you can give them your wanted constrains.

For example, if you want to center your view in the middle of the screen you can do **something like this:**

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textintro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Droid Desserts"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

- For more information on the subject, you can check [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)